# Angular 6: use the value of an @Input within an ngOnInit

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I'd like to retrieve the value of the model car by using an input, but I'm not sure of how it works. Here's what I've tried.

```
@Input() model : Car
car: Car;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.car= this.carService.getcar(model.id);
      }
```

Unfortunetaly model is always empty.How can I do?

EDIT:
 Parent HTML

```
 <app-model
        [model]="car">
  </app-model>
```

PARENT ts file

```
ngOnInit{
  this.shopService.get()
        .pipe(
          take(1),
          finalize(() => {
                    })
              )
         .subscribe(result => {
              this.car = result;
              });
          })
        )
 }
```

Comment: Your code seems OK, the @Input() property will get its value always before the ngOnInit(). Use Visual studio Code and tslint to avoid small problems with syntax. If your model is empty check the parent component

Comment: show your code of parent component where you are using this component and binding input model

Comment: Show your parent component

Comment: Assuming that your service is OK test using only .subscribe

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `@Input()` (with brackets)

Answer (score 2):

In HTML of another component

```
<app-detail-component [model]="{id: 1, name: 'Carname'}"></app-detail-component>
```

In the .ts file of your described component (I assumed the name of the Component is DetailComponent.ts)

```
@Input() model: Car;
car: Car;

ngOnInit() {
     this.car= this.carService.getcar(model.id);
}
```

Link to official documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 2):

`model` is empty because variable `car` in parent component is assigned after `ngOnInit` is invoked in the child component. You need to call a method of `carService` in `ngOnChanges`, not `ngOnInit`.

```
@Input() model: Car
car: Car;

ngOnChanges() {
  this.car = this.carService.getcar(model.id);
}
```